# Character arrays in a Struct

Tags: c, string, struct

If one wants to add a `char*` (string) array to a struct how does the syntax look?

e.g.

```
struct someStruct
{
     char **someStrings;
}
```

Where does one set the limit for the length of the array e.g. setting each member of `someString` to have a limit of ten chars?

Comment: Do you want to limit someString to hold ten strings or each string to hold ten chars?

Comment: each string to hold ten chars

Comment: I don't think you can really do this in C, not automatically anyway. The size of an array is not part of its type (like in Go).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know ahead of time how many strings you will need (call it M) and the maximum length for each string (call it N), then you'd just declare a 2D array of char:

```
#define M ... // number of strings
#define N ... // max length of each string

struct someStruct
{
  char someStrings[M][N+1];  // +1 for 0 terminator
  ...
};
```

If you don't know how many strings you'll need, but do know the max length, you can declare a pointer to an array of char:

```
#define N ...

struct someStruct
{
  char (*someStrings)[N+1];
  size_t numStrings;
  ...
};
```

Then, when you need to allocate your string array, you'd do something like:

```
struct someStruct s = {NULL, 0};
size_t count = getNumStrings();
s.someStrings = malloc(sizeof *s.someStrings * count);
if (s.someStrings)
  s.numStrings = count;
```

And now you can treat `someStrings` as an array of strings:

```
strcpy(s.someStrings[i], "foo");
printf("%s\n", s.someStrings[j]);
s.someStrings[i][j] = 'a';
```

When you're done with the array, release the memory like so:

```
free(s.someStrings);
```

**NOTE**: when dealing with pointers to arrays, you have to dereference the pointer before applying the subscript; given the code

```
T (*a)[N];
a = malloc(sizeof *a); // allocates a single N-element array of T
```

you would normally have to write `(*a)[i]` to properly access the i'th element of the array (`*a[i]` parses as `*(a[i])`, which is not what we want here).  Remember, however, that `a[0]` is equivalent to `*a`; applying the subscript to `a` implicitly dereferences it, so `a[0][i]` is equivalent to `(*a)[i]`.  If we allocated it as

```
a = malloc(sizeof *a * M); // allocates M N-element arrays of T
```

then we could reference each array as `a[0]`, `a[1]`, etc., and each element of each array as `a[0][0]`, `a[0][1]`, etc.  That's why you don't see any pointer gymnastics in the code above.

If you don't know how many strings or the max length for each string, you'll have to do a two-step allocation, like so:

```
struct someStruct
{
  char **someStrings;
  size_t numStrings;  
  size_t maxLength;
};

struct someStruct s = {NULL, 0, 0};
size_t count = getNumStrings();
s.maxLength = getMaxLength();
s.someStrings = malloc(sizeof *s.someStrings * count); 
if (s.someStrings)
{
  size_t i;
  s.numStrings = count;
  for (i = 0; i < s.numStrings; i++)
  {
    s.someStrings[i] = malloc(sizeof *s.someStrings[i] * s.maxLength + 1);
    if (s.someStrings[i])
      // initialize string value here
  }
}
```

Again, you can treat `someStrings` as an ordinary 2D array:

```
strcpy(s.someStrings[i], "foo");
printf("%s", s.someStrings[j]);
s.someStrings[i][j] = 'a';
```

Like allocation, deallocation is a two-step process:

```
for (i = 0; i < s.numStrings; i++)
  free(s.someStrings[i]);
free(s.someStrings);
```

Note that unlike the first two methods, this method doesn't guarantee that the strings are contiguous in memory.

You'll have to keep track of the number of strings and the max length for each string manually; there's no way to get that information from the pointer values alone.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define NUM_STRINGS 5 // for example
#define STRING_LENGTH 11 // for example

struct someStruct
{
    char stringArray[NUM_STRINGS][STRING_LENGTH];
}
```

from your question and your comments to other questions, it looks like this will do. your string array will hold 5 strings in this case, and each string will hold 10 characters and a null terminator. you may also do it with no defines, but the defines will make it easier to change later if you must resize.

Answer (score 0):

`char **` is an array of strings. A simple string is `char *`.

If you want to limit its length you can use `char someString[11]`. (+1 to include the null character at the end).

Comment: I want an array of strings and limit each string to e.g. 10 characters?